# Google's charts for your customers?

Tags: php, charts, google-visualization, privacy

Do you use Google's charts for your customers to view it?

Google's charts may show report of number of orders or finance. Customer can login to the website and see their orders.

I am concern what if customers start complainig that I am sending information to google.

What Chart library do you recommend that can be generated by PHP? I think this would probably be safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider rendering your charts with pure canvas as well:

http://code.google.com/p/flot/

That would put less load on your server, especially if you plan on generating the charts on the fly.

Comment: That is a good idea but I would get the data from mySQL - how would you put the value into Javascript code? Hmm

Comment: You would just have PHP render javascript data objects (preferably with any JSON-serializer).

Comment: I use Flot for reporting in my webstore just as previous commenter told, ie. by printing data from PHP script to page source as JSON. Highly recommended.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct; it may be a breach of your customers' data security to send information to Google. One library for php image generation is pchart (http://pchart.net/)

Comment: Wow, that is really nice chart. Thanks.